# OutOfmemory error when creating ArrayBlockingQueue with Integer.MAX_VALUE entries

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, collections, capacity

I have been using `LinkedBlockingQueue`, and recently changed this to `ArrayBlockingQueue` due to slow insertion performance. I got a significant performance improvement after that. However, my code sometime throws an out-of-memory error:

**My Java Code**

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<String> s = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

I looked the `ArrayBlockingQueue` source code. Really, I got shocked - it allocating an `object[]` for given initial capacity. This is the reason for the out-of-memory error.

**ArrayBlockingQueue Source Code**

```
public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair) {
    if (capacity <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.items = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    lock = new ReentrantLock(fair);
    notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    notFull =  lock.newCondition();
}
```

This doesn't guess the initial capacity or creates an queue with minimum capacity. Because it will be vary on peak time and normal time. If I give minimum capacity, queue will be filled immediately on peak hours. If I give max capacity I get an out of memory error and i does not want to allocate an object[] before inserting elements.

Please suggest any alternative.

Comment: Just start java with more memory? `-Xmx 32G` or whatever. Also, how else are you going to create a generic ArrayBlockingQueue?

Answer (score 6):

Remove the argument to the constructor.  Why does your queue need that much capacity?  Start with a reasonable number like 10 or 100 or 1000.

This line is ridiculous:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<String> s = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

You don't need an initial capacity of 2147483647.  That's 2GB just for the queue!

Comment: It's an fixed capacity. Queue will be filled quickly.

Comment: Not with 2GB entries it won't.  The idea is to add a pool of consumers that respond quickly enough that the queue is never filled.  If it does fill up, producers will block until room is freed up.  That's how queues work.